# Should the thread function return 0?

Tags: c, unix, posix, gcc-warning

I have this void function, with a pointer to my thread. when i go to compile, I get the warning: "control reaches end of non-void function". If I do

```
void mythread (void *arg)
```

and the function i will solve the warning that the compiler gives, but get a new warning, that says:

```
TA.c:50:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

So then, I put `return 0;` at the end of "mythread" function, and it compiles. But I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do?

I am trying to learn POSIX system service programing. I am not sure what to do.

Advice? Should I try and type cast argument 3? How can I compile my program, and get zero warnings?

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *mythread (void *arg)
{   
    printf("This my Thread Maybe...\n");    
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t mythread_id;
    pthread_attr_t mythread_attr;
    size_t stack_size;
    int detachstate;

    pthread_attr_init (&mythread_attr);
    pthread_attr_getdetachstate(&mythread_attr, &detachstate);
    if(detachstate == PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED)
    {
        printf("Current Deteached state is Detached\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Current Detached state is Joinable\n");
    }

    pthread_attr_setdetachstate (&mythread_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pthread_attr_getdetachstate (&mythread_attr, &detachstate);

    if(detachstate == PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED)
    {
        printf("NEW DETACHED STATE is determined to be deteched\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NEW DETACHED STATE is Determine to be Joinable\n");
    }

    pthread_attr_getstacksize (&mythread_attr, &stack_size);
    printf ("Default stack size is %d; minimum is %d\n", stack_size, PTHREAD_STACK_MIN);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize (&mythread_attr, PTHREAD_STACK_MIN*2);
    pthread_attr_getstacksize (&mythread_attr, &stack_size); 

    printf("NEW stack size is %d\n", stack_size);
    pthread_create (&mythread_id, &mythread_attr, mythread, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Every question here is looking for coding advice. Can you make your title more specific?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edit. yes i'm aware, stinky title. I tried 5 different titles, only this one made it through. Not sure about having to site hack titles to ask a simple question.

Comment: So, how do i mark this as solved? (Thanks all for the help)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding `return 0` to the end of the function is the right thing to do. The function signature is such that it should return a value. The `pthread` library code will expect a return value to be returned. Casting the thread function to the wrong signature would result in undefined behavior.

Your code can see the return result after a call to `pthread_join()`. You can use `0` to mean success. If that doesn't satisfy you, you can choose a different value.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) indicates that it requires a pointer to a function taking a `void *` and returning a `void *` as its third argument:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

This is why you get the "incompatible pointer type" warning when the function returns `void` instead of `void *` - it becomes a different type of function pointer.

A good solution is, as you mentioned, to make the function return a dummy `void *`, such as `return 0` (or perhaps less confusingly, `return NULL`), to make the function pointer types compatible.

Comment: When returning 0, will it automatically be converted to a void * pointer?

Answer (score 2):

"So Then, I put return 0; at the end of "mythread" function, and it compiles. But I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do? Advice? I am a newb programmer, trying to learn POSIX system service programing."

Yes it is. pthread_create needs to get passed a pointer to a procedure that takes one void pointer and returns a void pointer. Look at the prototype (from the man page)

```
   int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

Can you recognize the type of start_routine now?